# How can I edit a post with the API and python?

Tags: support

I am a real beginner, but want to know more about using the API.

I need to be able to get a post tagged with [installation](/questions/tagged/installation) and the have it displayed to me. I then enter either 1 or 2, and it will remove that tag and add [system-installation](/questions/tagged/system-installation) or [software-installation](/questions/tagged/software-installation) respectively.

Python would be the easiest for me, but I'm using Ubuntu so Bash is also fine.

I don't need a complete solution, but I would like some basic guidelines.

For example, what is the registration expecting for the OAuth 2.0 site? Do I need to own a site?

What is the `Enable Client Side OAuth Flow` for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK... I've just meddled with the API and editing.

So, to do what you want, here's what I would do (in steps:)

1. Get the questions via [`/questions`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions) with the `tagged` being `installation`. Use Python to loop through `items` (the results) and show them to you one-by-one. Make sure you make new variables saving the title, body and tags (so you can edit the question)
2. Use Python to let you say `1` or `2`, each calling a function `addTag`
3. The `if` statement you use for checking whether `1` or `2` has been inputted will call `addTag` with a parameter `newTag` being either `system-installation` or `software-installation`.

To edit:

Use [`/questions/{id}/edit`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/edit-question):

- title: same title
- body: same title
- tags: same tags **minus the `installation` and with the appropriate new tag (in the parameters)**
- summary: summary either pre-defined or `input()`ted on run.

Using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
def editQuestion(questionId, access_token, site_name, key, postText, postSummary, postTags, postTitle):
    results = requests.post("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/[question_ID]/edit",
              data={'body': postText,
                    'comment': postSummary,
                    'tags': postTags,
                    'title': postTitle,
                    'access_token': '[access token]',
                    'site': '[site_name]',
                    'key': '[key]'
                    }
    )

    print(results.text)
```

---

You use Client Side OAuth Flow mainly when you do not have a website yourself to let someone get an access token. So use this. [See here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) for more details on authentication. You would need to send a new user to:

> https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&scope=write_access&redirect_uri=http://stackexchange.com

^^edit the parameters as required!

Comment: Can I get the body source (markdown), rather than html?

Comment: @Tim Use the 'filter' to get the `body_markdown` (under `question`). (ie. `!9YdnSIoOi`) -> [this](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=support&fiter=!9YdnSIoOi&site=meta&run=true)